# how to use a noun phrase or verb phrase after "of"?

Tags: nouns

> the effects of the spraying of Matacil
>
> the effects of spraying of Matacil

I know you usually use the former, however, I wonder what is your opinion as to the latter!

Thanks

Comment: Is this a question on article usage?

Comment: No, it is on if you use the second one?

Comment: But the only difference is the absence of the definite article **the** in the second sentence. I wanted to know whether you were uncertain about article usage here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the spraying of Matacil is a piece of art.

In this case the second is wrong, as it does no longer reference to the piece of art, but instead references to the act of spraying. You cannot use of after spraying as an object or adverb is expected. The of does show some sort of possession or origin in here which just doesn't work with a verb.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence should read

> The effects of spraying Matacil

**of** is not necessary. Matacil is the object of verb spraying